# sql, function in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

```
DELIMITER $
CREATE FUNCTION MAXSCOREID(START_STUDENT_ID INT, END_STUDENT_ID INT)
RETURNS INT
BEGIN
DECLARE STUDENT_ID INT;
BEGIN
    SELECT MAX(SCORE) INTO STUDENT_ID 
    FROM STUDENT ST, SCORE S 
    WHERE ST.STUDENT_ID = S.STUDENT_ID
    AND ST.STUDENT_ID BETWEEN 1 AND 10;
END;
RETURN student_id;
END$
DELIMITER ;
```

Hi. With the function above, I get the higher score but I want to get the student`s id who has the max score.  Any help, please?

Comment: Also you're using inconsistent case on your variables, and not using your input parameters.

Comment: You can be certain that it works well. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace the body of your function with the following:

```
SELECT ST.STUDENT_ID INTO student_id
FROM STUDENT ST
LEFT JOIN SCORE S USING (STUDENT_ID)
WHERE ST.STUDENT_ID BETWEEN 1 AND 10
HAVING MAX(SCORE);
```

This uses the aggregate form of the `MAX()` function. I'd recommend reworking your function to differentiate variable names and column names; I'd also suggest using lower case column names to make your code easier to read!

Answer (score 1):

This query will produce the set of students who have the maximum score.

```
select student_id
from score
where score = (select max(score) from score);
```

Comment: It works itself but when I put it into the function, it returns null.

Comment: Your function is declared to return a single int (i.e., a single student), but there may be more than one student with the maximum score.  You will have to change the function to return a set of students or otherwise modify your process to adapt to the possibility of having multiple students with the maximum score.